# .NET ParameterizedThreadStart wrong return type

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters, methods, return-type

I just started experimenting with Threads and I ran in to a problem I'm not able to solve on my own. I get the error: Error 1   'bool projekt.ftp.UploadFil (object)' has the wrong return type

I use this code to start a thread using the method ftp.Uploadfile:

```
Thread ftpUploadFile = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ftp.UploadFile));
ftpUploadFile.Start(e.FullPath);
```

And this is the method I used.

```
public static bool UploadFile(object filename)
{
    string file = Convert.ToString(filename);

    /* blah blah fricken blah snip */

    return false; 

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `lok` object is thread-safe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the error message, you'll see that the problem is that the method has the wrong return type.

Specifically, your `UploadFile` method returns `bool`, but the `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate returns `void`.

To fix this, change the `UploadFile` method to return `void`, and change all of its `return xxx;` statements to `return;`.

Alternatively, you could wrap `UploadFile` in an anonymous method, like this:

```
Thread ftpUploadFile = new Thread(delegate { ftp.UploadFile(e.FullPath); });
ftpUploadFile.Start();
```

Comment: Thread ftpUploadFile = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { ftp.UploadFile(e.FullPath); }));

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to return anything from your method. [Make the return type void - as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx):

```
public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(Object obj)
```

If you need to know results from your method you need to look into [Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use an anynomous delegate like so:

```
bool result = false;    
ThreadStart s = delegate
{
    result = UploadFile(ftp.UploadFile);
};
Thread t = new Thread(s);
s.Start();
s.Join();
// now you have your result    
if (result)
{ // do something useful
}
```

Comment: In runtime, program will reach very quickly to line "if (result)". And you will not get any 'result' from UploadFile.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public static void UploadFile(object filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `ParameterizedThreadStart` is expecting a method with a `void` return type.